# WPF combobox bind with collections displayvaluepath,SelectedValuePath not working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Problem in WPF `ComboBox` item:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboSelectSeries"  Width="100" Height="25" Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="3" SelectedIndex="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="SeriesNumber" 
          DisplayMemberPath="NId" />
```

XAML.cs

```
internal List<NPIS.PortableObject.NPIS> NCollection;
..
NCollection=getdata();
cboSelectSeries.DataContext = NCollection;
```

Output:

with items as "NPIS.PortableObject.NPIS"

Comment: Its better to set Itemsource in your case... `cboSelectSeries.ItemsSource= NCollection;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code and it did worked.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<PortableObject> NCollection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NCollection = getdata();
        cboSelectSeries.DataContext = NCollection;
    }

    private List<PortableObject> getdata()
    {
        return new List<PortableObject>
                           {
                               new PortableObject
                                   {
                                       SeriesNumber = 001,
                                       NId = 10,
                                   },
                                    new PortableObject
                                   {
                                       SeriesNumber = 002,
                                       NId = 20,
                                   },
                                    new PortableObject
                                   {
                                       SeriesNumber = 003,
                                       NId = 30,
                                   },
                           };
    }
}

public class PortableObject
{
    public int SeriesNumber { get; set; }
    public int NId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried ur code in sample solution it is showing items with "NId", But When some item is selected it is not showing SeriesNumber.
Please help on that.

Comment: When you select an item, the item is basically a 'PortableObject' object, so to get SeriesNumber you need to have another property which should bind the SelectedItem property of ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it could not find property path `NId` in class `NPIS`. Make sure you have *public exposed property* in underlying class. Also path name is *case sensitive*, make sure path name and property name is correct.

```
public int NId { get; set; }
```